# Scripts overlapping/cancelling each other out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing what should be very simple HTML CSS and Jquery code, but since I'm somewhat new to this stuff I'm still having trouble figuring it out. please help.. I'm trying to get the slideshow on this page http://vbwtest.comeze.com/index.php to be exactly the same as the slideshow on http://vbwpublishing.3dcartstores.com/

there are 2 problems with it though. On my vbwtest site, the button to switch images won't show up and then the obvious problem of the script not working. It used to, but then I changed something/added some jquery and it all broke. So if someone could enlighten me in what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way you can narrow the problem down a little more for us and provide some `//example code`? Not everyone is going to jump on those two pages and want to compare potentially hundreads of lines of source code.

Comment: it is no fun dealing with scripts that you don't understand, but are interacting negatively. my advice is to add/remove scripts/functions one by one to see where the problem lies. then people will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the sites code with firebug, i have noticed the arrow image wont load because it is linked incorrectly in the css file.

With regards to the script not working, the slider works fine. Even the arrow button works without the image.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I linked the arrow image properly in css now, but for some reason it still won't show up. I'll figure it out I'm sure.